# how to calculate the two days or 3 days total amounts in my sql

Tags: sql

how to calculate the 2 days or 3 days total amounts in MySQL.

a sum of 3 days amounts and sum of 2 days amounts

how to write a query in MySql

Comment: MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Tag you correct RDBMS and format your question with sample data and required output. text only question will not have responses.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I removed those conflicting tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: @jarlh '2017-11-01', '3315.190482161' '2017-11-02', '39329.44302623501' '2017-11-03', '336.83803510399997' '2017-11-04', '-0.6' '2017-11-05', '3122.536061919' '2017-11-07', '6292.578826358001' '2017-11-08', '4808.605014354001' '2017-11-09', '3600.869093371'

I want 4th and 5th dates sum of amounts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your relation looks like but if I get it right you want to `SUM` one column over the past 2 or 3 days which will be something like:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(yourColumnName)
FROM tableName
WHERE entry.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 days
```

For 3 days you have to set `INTERVAL 3 days`

Comment: '2017-11-01', '3315.190482161' '2017-11-02', '39329.44302623501' '2017-11-03', '336.83803510399997' '2017-11-04', '-0.6' '2017-11-05', '3122.536061919' '2017-11-07', '6292.578826358001' '2017-11-08', '4808.605014354001' '2017-11-09', '3600.869093371'

I want 4th and 5th dates sum of amounts.

Comment: Sorry @Prem I really don't get it.